# Insert a tag with a unique identifier into a XML

Tags: xml, xmlstarlet

I'm able to add a new node with a custom fixed value to my XML file in this way, with [xmlstarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net):

```
xmlstarlet ed --subnode "/legge190/data/lotto" --type elem -n newsubnode \
-v "myvalue"
```

But how to add a unique identifier?

If I try to add a unique identifier using `generate-id(.)`

```
xmlstarlet ed --subnode "/legge190/data/lotto" --type elem -n newsubnode \
-v "generate-id(.)"
```

I do not have an id value, but the `generate-id(.)` string.

Thank you

Comment: can you post your initial xml file content?

Comment: Hi @RomanPerekhrest I would like a custom tag after <cig> tag https://gist.github.com/aborruso/262eb8ed5e8427176ffda7ce4b3d5538#file-00samplestart-xml-L9.
It would be fanstastic to add ass value an ID generated via `generate-id(.)`

Comment: do you want a `newsubnode` to look as `<newsubnode>5329384ACB</newsubnode>` ?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest, yes I want something like `<newsubnode>5329384ACB</newsubnode>`, not writing `-v "5329384ACB"`, but using an XPATH function like  `-v "generate-id(.)"`. Thank you

Comment: unfortunately, `generate-id` function won't work in  xmlstarlet edit `ed` mode. I can suggest a solution for copying id from node `<cig>` to node `<newsubnode>`

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest please give a solution for copying id from node <cig> to node <newsubnode>. 
But however I need a way to add unique identifier in the new node (unfortunately cig is not) .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved with a `xsl` file like this one:

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="cig">
    <lottoID><xsl:value-of select="generate-id(.)"/></lottoID>
<!-- a linefeed -->
    <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The `id` is generated by `generate-id` XPATH function.

In this way I copy all nodes and insert a unique identifier in the `<lottoID>` element just before the `<cig>` element (that is a element of my [input XML file](https://gist.github.com/aborruso/262eb8ed5e8427176ffda7ce4b3d5538#file-00samplestart-xml)).

The command with [xmlstarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net)  is:

```
xmlstarlet tr stile.xsl input.xml
```

Comment: When you edit something, please provide an Edit Summary that summarizes the edit: something like “Updated URL of homepage.”